# queue async jquery effects on different divs with a sync function call

Tags: jquery

I want to fade out div1. Then fade in div2. Then execute the doStuffAtTheEnd function.

I thought when each effect takes a callback everything is synchron. But I never see the fade in of div2. Its just visible immediatelly without fade in effect.

Why is that?

```
$('#div1').fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $('#div2').fadeIn(1000), function(){           
            doStuffAtTheEnd();
        }); 
});
```

Comment: make sure `div2` is hidden in default..

Comment: @bipen and where should I call the .show() then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have incorrect closing bracket `)`

try this

```
$('#div1').fadeOut(1000, function () {
   $('#div2').fadeIn(1000, function(){  
                   //----^----here         
        doStuffAtTheEnd();
    }); 
});
```

and make sure `div2` is hidden in default.

**updated**

add `display:none` in your css for the div2 or hide it it document.ready function `$('#div2').hide()`... created this example fiddle (assuming this is what you want)...

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/9Ncrr/)

Comment: nah sorry thats just a typo not the original problem.

Comment: @Elisa updated please check.. fadeIn by default shows the hidden elements

Comment: the trick was the .hide() initially for the div I want to .fadeIn(). I have created a good example here where you see 3 effects syncronyously done on 2 different divs: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ncrr/1/

Comment: damn... I do not understand this, but the above sample link points to an old updated code. Seems something went wrong with copy/paste dont know or someone deleted the fiddle if thats possible at all.

Comment: i think you forgot to update your fiddle.. anyways hope you fixed it and this helped.. happy coding

Comment: yes looking back I also thought that... its not always the others ;P